# changing a web browsers default scroll bar advice

Tags: website-design

So, I want to change my browsers scroll bar to something a little nicer looking like the scrollbar that www.twitch.tv uses.

But then I noticed that not many other websites change their scrollbars. Is there a reason for that?

Is it best to leave them as default?